# css borders with equal spacing

Tags: html, css, border

I'm sure that there is a very basic way to fix my problem. Unfortunately, I'm really inexperienced in front-end development, but I have to fix my problem. Briefly, there are some dynamic border boxes in my table but it should be some spaces between every border box.

Now it looks like  below image

[image: now]

However, it should be like below image

[image: Sample Picture]

My code is below. How can I do this with changing the CSS?

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
.chart {
  border: solid 1px #e31515;
  color: #e31515;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<span style="overflow: hidden;left: 550px; height: 150px;  width: 250px; position: absolute; "> <div >
<table cellpadding="2" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="overflow: hidden; border-top: #e9e8e8 1px solid; border-right: 0px; width: 1%; white-space: nowrap; border-bottom: #e9e8e8 1px solid; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; border-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: transparent">
        <div class="bg" style="height: 129px">
          <div class="chart" style="height: 14px; margin-top: 115px"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="overflow: hidden; border-top: #e9e8e8 1px solid; border-right: 0px; width: 1%; white-space: nowrap; border-bottom: #e9e8e8 1px solid; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; border-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: transparent">
        <div class="bg" style="height: 129px">
          <div class="chart" style=" height: 14px; margin-top: 115px"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</span>
<span style="overflow: hidden;left: 150px; height: 150px;  width: 250px; position: absolute; ">
        <div >
            <table  cellpadding="2" border="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td  style="overflow: hidden; border-top: #e9e8e8 1px solid; border-right: 0px; width: 1%; white-space: nowrap; border-bottom: #e9e8e8 1px solid; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; border-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: transparent" >
                            <div class="bg" style="height: 129px">
                                <div class="chart" style="height: 14px; margin-top: 115px"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="overflow: hidden; border-top: #e9e8e8 1px solid; border-right: 0px; width: 1%; white-space: nowrap; border-bottom: #e9e8e8 1px solid; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; border-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: transparent" >
                            <div class="bg" style="height: 129px">
                                <div class="chart" style="height: 14px; margin-top: 115px"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="overflow: hidden; border-top: #e9e8e8 1px solid; border-right: 0px; width: 1%; white-space: nowrap; border-bottom: #e9e8e8 1px solid; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; border-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: transparent" >
                            <div class="bg" style="height: 129px">
                                <div class="chart" style="height: 14px; margin-top: 115px"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using padding. Instead, you need to use margin property. In box model, the padding is used for aligning the inside contents of a box. However, since you are applying the style to the , you need to mention margin-right property of each . Simply replace padding with margin property in bg style.

`.bg {
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: 2px;
            margin-right: 2px;
        }`

Hope this helps. If you find this solution correct, mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

CSS border-spacing property does what you need.

```
table{
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

Example here: http://www.w3schools.com/csSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_border-spacing

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work because I'm drawing the borders in a div using a css such as <div class="chart" style="height: 14px; margin-top: 115px"></div> Because of this, I need to draw these borders with a space